# play sounds on touch on image

Tags: android, coordinates, android-imageview, touch-event, soundpool

am developing an application which play sounds when user touches on a image.
i create my own sound file. in this case i have 3 doubts,

1. In which folder i need to place sound file.??
2. which method is suitable for playing sounds..
3. how can i detect where the user touch on the image, because i need to play different sound when user touches at different places.

hope that u understand my idea.......pls help me....

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    touchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

private void touchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by which method is right to play sound?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You should place sound files in `/res/raw` folder.

**2.** Use the following code to play the sound

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity,R.raw.sound_file);
                 mp.start();
```

**3.**  Attaching a `TouchListener` will allow you to handle the `MotionEvent`, which contains the actual touch position; just do something like the following

```
if(event.getX() < image.width / 2) { 
    // touch on left 
} else { 
    // touch on right;
}
```

You can further refine your touch position also by adding more logic.

Comment: @Vikky If you feel that your problem is solved then please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In which folder i need to place sound file.??

`raw folder` if not present in res then create one.

Answer (score 0):

**Sound File in  res/raw folder**

Firstly, Get x and y coordinates then put your conditions onTouch and try to use the below code to play music

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        mPlayer2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`In which folder i need to place sound file.??`

Usually files (mp3, csv, pdf) files are placed inside the `Raw` folder.

`Which method is suitable for playing sounds..`

There is no such simple method. You need to make use of [MediaPlayer class](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

`how can i detect where the user touch on the image, because i need to play different sound when user touches at different places.`

Add a `onClickEventListener` to the ImageView and invoke the MediaPlayer instance from there.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can user Event OnClick

```
    MediaPlayer song;
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            song=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songname);
            song.start();
        }
    });
```